# Every countable closed set in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ has isolated points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The above statement is the Corollary to exercise 28 of chapter 2 in Baby Rudin.  It seems to me like the Cantor set is an obvious exception to this statement.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Cantor set is not countable.

Comment: Haha, +1. Surely you could have broken the news more gently.

Comment: @Mike: How would you suggest? :)

Comment: @Ted: "Hi there, Josh.  Do you have a moment?  How are you doing?  That's great.  And your family?  I'm so glad to hear it.  You look thin, by the way: young and thin, actually.  Well, buddy, the thing is that the Cantor set is not countable.  Actually it can be put in bijection with the interval $[0,1]$ so it has continuum cardinality.  One way to see it is with decimal expansions; there are lots of other good ways.  But Josh, I just want to emphasize that we don't think any less of you or anything like that.  You have a bright future here: you know that, right?  Have a great day, friend!"

Comment: @Pete: Glad to see you're in the right frame of mind for your linear algebra students! :)